# Concatenate cells in excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have two columns of data as follows:

`A1: A; A2: B; A3: C and B1: 1; B2:2; B3:3`

Is there a simple loop in VBA to have on column `C` the concatenated values as:

`C1: A1; C2: A2; C3: A3; C4: B1; C5: B2; C6: B3;` etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't see it any simpler than below

```
Sub concat()

Dim i As Integer

    With ActiveSheet
        For i = 1 To .UsedRange.Rows.Count
            .Cells(i, 3) = .Cells(i, 1) & .Cells(i, 2)
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

Or maybe there is:

```
Sub concat2()

    With ActiveSheet
        .Range("C1") = "=CONCATENATE(RC[-2],RC[-1])"
        .Range("C1").AutoFill Destination:=.Range("C1:C" & .UsedRange.Rows.Count)
    End With

End Sub
```

That would also make non-vba users understand what column C actually is ;)

Answer (score 1):

I would use modulo arithmetic to achieve this. The subroutine below assumes that the last row in column `C` that needs to be populated is `lLastRow` (I set it `=25` for testing):

```
Sub test()

    Dim lLastRow As Long, ACnt As Long, BCnt As Long
    ACnt = 1

    ' Last row of column C that needs to be filled with Data
    lLastRow = 25

    For BCnt = 1 To lLastRow
        ' Use modulo arithmetic to point to the right cell in column B
        Cells(BCnt, 3) = Cells(ACnt, 1) & IIf(BCnt Mod 3 <> 0, BCnt Mod 3, 3)
        ' We should increment column A every three rows
        ACnt = IIf((Cells(BCnt, 3).Row) Mod 3 = 0, ACnt + 1, ACnt)
        ' Reset column A pointer when we go beyond 3
        ACnt = IIf(ACnt = 4, 1, ACnt)
    Next BCnt

End Sub
```

**Column B number:**
The idea is that (starting from the first row), the `modulo` of each row and `3` will be `0,1,2` and will recycle in this fashion forever. Whenever the row number is a multiple of `3`, the `modulo` returns `0` and therefore we need to refer to `3` on column `B` (i.e., cell (`B3`). Else, `modulo` returns exactly what we want (which is either `1` or `2`).

**Column A number:**
This is simpler: every `3rd` row we switch row.. So when `(Cells(BCnt, 3).Row) Mod 3 = 0`, we increment the pointer of column `A`. Of course, when we reach the `4th` row, we need to return back to the `1st` row.

I hope this helps!!

Comment: @mehow Thanks for the vote :) Yes, that is why I avoid to nest the two of them. In that case the inner `IIF` statement would be re-evaluated whenever `ACnt <> 4`.. Also, (as you probably imply), if one of the two conditions is `false` and raises an error then `IIF` will raise an error as well, which is indeed good to keep in mind.

Comment: @mehow Well, according to the other answers below, yes. I interpreted the "concatenated values" as the values whose first character comes from column `A` and the second character comes from column `B`. It was fun dealing with this anyway :)

Comment: yeah, the question title should be reworded to something like 'list all possible combinations using the concatenate techinque' :)

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to avoid VBA when possible, so given a data setup like this:

[image: tigeravatar formula solution for user2759430]

The formula in cell C1 and copied down is:

```
=IF(ROW(A1)>COUNTA(A:B),"",INDEX(A:B,MOD(ROW(A1)-1,COUNTA(A:A))+1,1+(ROW(A1)>COUNTA(A:A))))
```

*EDIT*

As an alternate interpretation, pointed out by Ioannis, given a data setup like this:

[image: tigeravatar formula solution for user2759430 v2]

The formula in cell C1 and copied down is:

```
=IF(ROW(A1)>COUNTA(A:A)*COUNTA(B:B),"",INDEX(A:A,INT((ROW(A1)-1)/COUNTA(B:B))+1)&INDEX(B:B,1+MOD(ROW(A1)-1,COUNTA(B:B))))
```

Comment: I think the OP is about concatenating the values (strings+numbers) that are found in `Range("A1:B3")`. It says column C should be: `A1, A2, A3, B1, B2, B3`, etc. I would interpret `etc` as continue with `C1, C2, C3` and then again `A1, A2, A3, ...`. Would that be possible without VBA? I see where you are coming from, the OP is somewhat confusing..

Comment: Do you mean a formula like `=A1&B1` copied down?  And yeah, the question mentions concatenation, but doesn't actually describe that as being the end goal, so I went with what was described as the end goal.

Comment: oooh, I think I know what you mean, combine the "A" and the "1" from `A1` and `B1` so that C1 shows "A1", then combine the "A" and the "2" from `A1` and `B2` so that C2 shows "A2" and so on.  I'll have to work on that, thanks for the alternate interpretation, that is probably the intended solution.

Comment: Exactly, that is what I did with VBA but not sure how I would go about it with excel - it would be cool! Yes, the question is not that clear..

Comment: @Ioannis I have edited my answer to include a formula solution for the interpretation you pointed out :)

Answer (score 0):

Can't you do something like:

```
Dim i,j AS int
For i = 1 to 3
 For j = 1 to 6
  NewVal = C(j):A(i)
 Next j
Next i
```

This is untested, but gives you direction of where to go..

Comment: answers should be solving the problems and not only suggest what to do. Your code fails, it shouldve perhaps been a comment.

Comment: Sorry.  Since I am a "new kid" here, had to raise my reputation level to add comments.  I understand a comment is way different than an anwser - sorry for the transgression.  - Kent